# MongoDB insert document after build index?

Tags: mongodb

Consider I have insert a dozen of documents of this format:

```
{"name":"some one", "age":32}
```

and then I build the index on the "name" property using the "unique" parameter.

When I insert a new document of the same format, do I need to rebuild the index on name after every insert or this is automated? Also upon new insertion with same name, because of the unique param, would the old document be deleted? Or the insertion just won't happen?

Using mongo 2.4.12 btw.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to create index again

if you use

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { field_to_be_index: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
```

it will drop the duplicate document on creating index.

See the full documentation of duplicate dropping for more information.

**WARNING: as the document says,
Specifying { dropDups: true } may delete data from your database. Use with extreme caution.**

after creating the unique index, if you index with non-unique filed, you will receive `duplicate key error index: ...` error

[More info about unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

Comment: In recent versions of MongoDB "dropDups" has been removed.